# Как перевернуть картинку при сохранении в Андроид

Tags: java, android, камера

Включаю камеру изображение показывается правильно, делаю фото и отправляю его в нужное мне Activity

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AcceptNotAccept.class);
            intent.putExtra("picture", data);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

принимаю его

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_not_accept);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivForAcceptPicture)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Изображение выводиться повернутым на 90 градусов влево... Уже 2 часа копаюсь в поисках решения... Подскажите кто знает как решить?

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Этот код работает когда мы выводим картинку, но когда картинка уже есть и ее нужно перевернуть то это не совсем подходящее решение

Answer (score 0):

Эта функция работает отлично

```
private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) {
    if (degrees != 0 && b != null) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2, (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
            if (b != b2) {
                b.recycle();
                b = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: может и работает, только делает абсолютно не то ,о чем спрашивает автор...

Comment: Случайно не тот код вставил. Этот код правильный. Пробуйте!